# Why is my program looping infinitely?

Tags: infinite-loop, do-while

My program skips past the option for the user to enter the squareSide and keeps looping.

Code is as follows:

```
do
    {
        //Displays menu
        cout << "Please select a geometric shape." << endl << endl;
        cout << "s:" << setw(10) << "Square" << endl;
        cout << "c:" << setw(10) << "Circle" << endl;
        cout << "d:" << setw(10) << "Diamond" << endl;
        cout << "t:" << setw(10) << "Triangle" << endl;
        cout << "e:" << setw(10) << "Exit" << endl << endl;

        cin >> letter;

        cout << "You selected " << letter << endl;

        if  (letter != EXIT || letter == EXIT1)
        {
            if (letter == SQUARE || letter == SQUARE1)
            {
                int squareSide;
                int character;

                cout <<"\nPlease enter the ASCII character you would like to use to print your square" << endl;
                cin >> character;

                cout << "\nPlease enter the length of one side of your square"
                << endl;

                cin >> squareSide;

                for (int x=0; x < squareSide; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < squareSide; y++)
                    {
                        cout << character;
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }

            }

        }

    } while (letter != EXIT && letter != EXIT1);
    return 0;
}
```

All menu selections have to be char.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say because letter never equals EXIT or EXIT1, whatever those are.

Comment: I has SQUARE = 's' and SQUARE1 = 'S'